# Skipping Kinect events

Tags: kinect

Kinect sensor raises many events per second and if you are not very fast to elaborate them (for example trying to animate a true 3D character) in a few frames you get stuck.

What is the best approach to handle only the reasonable number of events, without blocking the User Interface?

Thanks.

Comment: What Kinect SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest requesting the frame in a loop instead of using the event method. 
To do this in your animation loop just call:

`sensor.DepthStream.OpenNextFrame(millisecondsWait);`

Or:

```
sensor.SkeletonStream.OpenNextFrame(millisecondsWait);
```

Or:

```
sensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(millisecondsWait);
```

Event driven programming is great but when you run into problems like you mention it is better to just call the functions when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that if you're animating something really quick and elaborate (e.g. complex 60fps 3D image), the time you'll take to get the image from the camera synchronously might create bumps in your rendering.

I'd try splitting the rendering and the Kinect processing/polling in separate threads; with that approach you could even keep using the 30fps event-driven model.